# Can Giraph reuse the graph in memory from previous job for subsequent jobs?

Tags: memory, distributed, distributed-computing, graph-databases, giraph

I've around million nodes & billion edges, so does Giraph keep the graph in memory such that it can be used again for subsequent jobs or does it loads & stores the complete graph before & after every job respectively?

Answer (score 1):

What do you mean for subsequent jobs?? When you launch a graph algorithm (shortest path for example), Giraph loads the underlying graph in-memory and keeps it until the computation completed (all super-steps done). If check-pointing is enabled Giraph stores current state of all vertices at the end of some super-steps (depending on configurations) for fault-tolerance purposes. After the computation completed results are stored in HDFS (or something else like Hbase) and Java processes are terminated. There is not any rational reasons that Giraph keeps the graph in-memory for subsequent graph algorithms.